# PHP Exception error not working

Tags: php, validation

I have a very simple HTML form that contains a Username, Password, and Password confirmation field. The form is sent to a PHP file for input validation. The PHP validation file implements Exceptions and a try/catch block. The way it currently work is if I submit the form without entering any of the form fields, it only returns an error on the first field. Id like for it to detect that all the fields are missing and throw an error for all missing fields.

Here is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>User Registration</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Register new account</h3>
        <form action="HW4_action_exceptions.php" method="post">
            Username:
            <br/>
            <input type="text" name = "user_name"/>
            <br/>
            Password:
            <br/>
            <input type="password" name ="pass_word" />
            <br/>
            Confirm:
            <br/>
            <input type="password" name = "pass_cfm" />
            <br/>
            <input type="submit" name="register" value="Register">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is my PHP file:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {


    //put the submitted values into regular variables

    $user_name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $pass_word = $_POST['pass_word'];
    $pass_cfm = $_POST['pass_cfm'];

    //make an array of field names and data types

    $field_names = array("user_name" => "string",
        "pass_word" => "string",
        "pass_cfm" => "string");

    try {
        form_validate($field_names);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        echo "<br>";
    }

     if (!isset($e) and isset($_POST['register'])) 
     {
        echo "Thanks for your entry. We'll be in touch.";
     }
     else 
     {
        echo "correct form";
     }


}// main if

function form_validate($fns) {

    foreach ($fns as $key => $value) {

        $field_value = $key;

        global $$field_value;

        //echo "actual field value is " . $$field_value . "<br>";   

        switch ($value) {

            Case "string";

                if ((strlen($$field_value) < 1) or ( strlen($$field_value) > 99)) {
                    throw new Exception("Please enter a string value between 1 and 100 characters in the <b>$key</b> field");
                }

                break;

            default;

                break;
        }
    }
}

// test_input
?>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Don't throw an exception, just save the error messages inside an array and return the array as a response of calling form_validate() function, if the array is not empty then you can display all the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this will not work with Exceptions. When an Exception is thrown, the catch-block is executed immediately so everything in the try-block that follows will be skipped.

You might try using an array where you store all error messages that occurred.

```
$errors = array();
switch ($value) {
  Case "string";
    if ((strlen($$field_value) < 1) or ( strlen($$field_value) > 99)) {
      $errors[] = "Please enter a string value between 1 and 100 characters in the <b>$key</b> field");
    }
    break;
...
}
```

and then

```
if (count($errors) == 0 and isset($_POST['register'])) 
 {
    echo "Thanks for your entry. We'll be in touch.";
 }
 else 
 {
    echo "correct form";
 }
```

I hope this works for you.